# Crop selected area in all videos

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, linux

I have many videos in a folder which I want to crop in same way. 
I want to remove 25px from the bottom part of all frames of all videos. All the videos are 1280x720p and have same format which is mp4.

How can I crop 25px from the bottom of the frames and save the output files as new separate files?

I am using ffmpeg cli on Linux but I don't mind using other tools on Windows or Linux. Is there a easy way of doing this in batch?

Answer (score 3):

Basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf crop=iw:ih-25:0:0 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Note that MP4s usually require the dimensions to be even, so the command above will actually crop 26 pixels from the bottom.

On linux, using bash, the script would be

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./crop.sh

mkdir cropped
for file in *.mp4;
do
    ffmpeg -i "${file}" -vf crop=iw:ih-25:0:0 -c:a copy "./cropped/$file"
done
```